# Micro Front end Project causes Maximum call stack size exceeded after Live server reload

Tags: micro-frontend, nomachine-nx

[Error Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzzdZ.jpg)I have created Angular 15 Micro front end project using NX. Everything works fine on the first run with " nx serve host --devRemotes=remote" I have a Host project and a remote project. When I try to modify the code and when the web pack server live reload happens, I am getting Maximum call stack size exceeded and the browser shows blank page. I have shared libraries across the micro front end projects. I have been toiling with it for multiple days any insight or help is appreciated.

I need to get rid of Maximum call stack size exceeded error and so I can see the UI rendering after modifying the code and live reload.

Exception

```
main.ts:1 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at main.js:894:55
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at __webpack_require__.f.consumes (main.js:877:35)
at ensure chunk:6:1
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at __webpack_require__.e (ensure chunk:5:1)
at Object.get (main.js:418:559)
at get (main.js:558:25)
at getStrictSingletonVersion (main.js:528:19)
at main.js:611:19
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this exact issue myself and the solution was to check my shared libraries and make sure whenever they imported **from themselves** they used relative paths (IE import { ServiceOne } from '../../service-one/service-one.ts') instead of importing using the paths defined in the tsconfig (IE import { ServiceOne } from '@lib-one')